# Is there a way to update the same variable inside a loop in Mongo Db

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to update the same variable inside a loop in Mongo Db

```
{
    $project : {
        "taxedData":{ 
                 $map:
                  {
                     input: "$rateTaxLevel",
                     as: "taxIds",
                     in: { 
                                $map:
                                {
                                input: "$taxValidity",
                                as: "levels",
                                in: { 

                                    chargeAmount:
                                    {
                                        $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$taxIds.taxid", "$$levels.taxid" ] }, 
                                        { $divide: [ "$chargeAmount",{ $add: [ 1, "$$levels.tax_validityval" ]} ] }
                                        , "$$REMOVE" ]
                                    }
                                    }
                                }   

                          }
                  }
         }
    }
}
```

How can I carry forward the $chargeAmount variable to the next iteration of the loop

Comment: Could you show a sample document and expected result ?

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("5caae957beca0f79bddc46d9"), 
    "taxedData" : [ [  {
                "chargeAmount" : 66.66666666666667
            }
        ],[ 
            {
                "chargeAmount" : 33.333333333333336
            }
        ], [
            {
                "chargeAmount" : 98.0392156862745
            }
        ], [ 
            {
                "chargeAmount" : 81.30081300813008
            }
        ], [ 
       {
                "chargeAmount" : 99.00990099009901
            }
        ]]
}

I want to use the same chargeAmount in the next iteration

Comment: Here the chargeAmount is calculated and the value of the chargeAmount is not passed to the next iteration example
{iteration 1 : chargeamount = 95 -5 }
{iteration 2 charge amount should be 90 not 95 }